# TIdHTTP: Check for valid cookies before sending request?

Tags: delphi, cookies, delphi-xe2, indy, idhttp

I'm using Indy `TIdHTTP` along with `TIdCookieManager`. I would like to check the current cookies for the request I'm about to send and identify the likelyhood that it will be valid (I know I can't be 100% sure the server will accept my request). If there are no cookies, or if they're expired, I will want to login first and acquire new cookies. Otherwise, just send the request.

How would I go about doing such a check? I believe I have to check the cookie manager before I send a request, but don't know what to check.

Comment: You should request the actual page and check if the content matches an autenthicated webpage or some error message. That is the only way you can see the server is accepting your cookies ;)

Comment: You can't check the validity of a cookie, that's the server's task/responsablity. The cookie could be encrypted so it's useless...

Comment: No, but you can check if the cookie has expired, at least.  You can ask `TIdCookieManager` for a list of cookies for the URL you want to send a request to, and see if it actually includes the cookie in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function CheckCookies(Cookies: TIdCookieManager; const TargetURL: String): Boolean; 
var 
  URL: TIdURI;
  Headers: TIdHeaderList;  
begin 
  Result := False; 

  URL := TIdURI.Create(TargetURL);
  try
    Headers := TIdHeaderList.Create(QuoteHTTP);
    try  
      Cookies.GenerateClientCookies(URL, False, Headers);
      Result := Headers.Count > 0;
    finally
      Headers.Free;
    end;
  finally
    URL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

.

```
if not CheckCookies(IdHTTP1.CookieManager, 'http://www.someurl.com/') then
begin
  // login and get new cookies ...
end;
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but shouldn't it be `if CheckCookies()` and not `if not CheckCookies()`? Or actually it really depends on the intended use, I'll presumably want to handle both events.

Comment: I went off the assumption that `...` would be the portion to re-login and get new cookies. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Like already stated in the comments you cannot perform an actual acceptance check on the client, only the server can do that.

However you can filter out expired or invalid cookies:

```
function filterInvalidCookies(cookies: TIdCookies; targetURL: TIdURI): Boolean;
var
  c: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;

  c := 0;
  while (cookies.Count > c) do
    if (not cookies[c].IsExpired and cookies[c].IsAllowed(targetURL, False) and 
      (cookies[c].CookieName <> '')) then
      begin
      Result := True;
      Inc(c);
      end
    else
      cookies.Delete(c);
end;
```

The function removes invalid cookies and returns False if there are no valid ones left. Call it before a request like this:

```
if (Assigned(con.CookieManager)) then
  filterInvalidCookies(con.CookieManager.CookieCollection,
    TIdURI.Create('http://www.someurl.com/'));
```

where `con` is an `TIdHTTP` object.

You can do additional, maybe target page specific checks of course.

Comment: There is an easier way to eliminate expired cookies - call the `TIdCookieManager.GenerateClientCookies()` method.  It will delete expired cookies before then filling out the output list with the reamining matching cookies. In a future release of `TIdCookieManager` (already in the works), it will have several new methods (`RemoveExcessCookies()`, `RemoveExpiredCookies()`, and `RemoveNonPersistentCookies()`) to provide more control over cookie management.

Comment: Looks like a good solution but all I need is to check if a particular cookie exists and if it's not expired. I don't necessarily need to delete them, although I'm sure it would help.